# How to remove rows with duplicate values in some columns, while keeping values that are different?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe in the following format.

```
| id | name    | last_name | address | x       | y | x_list    | y_list|
| -- | ------- | --------- | ------- | ------- | - | --------- | ----- |
| 1  | 'John'  | 'Smith'   | 'add_1' | 'one'   | 1 | ['one']   | [1]   |
| 2  | 'Tom'   | 'Davis'   | 'add_2' | 'two'   | 2 | ['two']   | [2]   |
| 3  | 'John'  | 'Smith'   | 'add_1' | 'three' | 3 | ['three'] | [3]   |
| 4  | 'Tom'   | 'Davis'   | 'add_2' | 'four'  | 4 | ['four']  | [4]   |
| 5  | 'Susan' | 'Jones'   | 'add_1' | 'one'   | 1 | ['one']   | [1]   |
```

I have no idea how to approach this problem. I need this output:

```
| id | name    | last_name  | address | x_list           | y_list |
| -- | ------- | ---------- | ------- | ---------------- | ------ |
| 1  | 'John'  | 'Smith'    | 'add_1' | ['one', 'three'] | [1, 3] |
| 2  | 'Tom'   | 'Davis'    | 'add_2' | ['two', 'four']  | [2, 4] |
| 3  | 'Susan' | 'Jones'    | 'add_1' | ['one']          | [1]    |
```

Basically, I need to return a new DataFrame, or modify the existing one so the columns with **the same name, last_name, and address** have their x_list and y_list merged. Can anyone help me how to do this in pandas? This needs to be done on a dataframe of about 58 000 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then use following code:

```
df.groupby(['name', 'last_name', 'address'])[['x_list', 'y_list']].sum().reset_index()
```

output:

```
    name    last_name   address x_list          y_list
0   John    Smith       add_1   [ one , three ] [ 1 , 3 ]
1   Susan   Jones       add_1   [ one ]         [ 1 ]
2   Tom     Davis       add_2   [ two , four ]  [ 2 , 4 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I could see, your `x_list` and `y_list` columns are redundant data that contain `x` and `y` variables in list form. If my observation is right, there is no issue with dropping those two variables. You can use a `groupby` with `list` aggregation.

Assuming the `id` variable is your index, it will go something like this

```
df.groupby(['name','last_name','address'], as_index=False).agg(list)
```

Comment: They are not redundant, because I need those lists for further analysis. Some x entries are long strings (I will give you an example, not from this dataframe, but it illustrates the real data well: 'apple | orange | pear'), so I needed to break them into lists.

Comment: Your desired output doesn't show how you intend to handle `x` and `x_list`. Please provide a better example if the two variables are unrelated.

Comment: OK, thank you for your answer. Initially, I had just x and y. However, since x and y were long lists of items, I had to break them into x_list and y_list. SinceI have some rows that share name, last_name, address, but are different in x and y, I thought just to drop x and y columns in the final output, and add all content of those to x_list and y_list, just like I added in the table above. I am sorry if it was not clear enough.